# Calling a jquery mobile function from an external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have written an exernal js file and in it is one function. In this function I am trying to call $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); How would I do this? I have tried the following and it doesnt work:

```
function test() {
     $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
}
```

The order of script inclusion on the html is shown below:

```
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>

<script src="master.js"></script>
```

and master.js is the one that makes the call.

Comment: If you see the javascript console, do you see any error? Have you used the file AFTER the jquery mobile library inclusion?

Comment: Cannot call method 'showPageLoadingMsg' of undefined

Comment: This means that you have included your external file BEFORE the inclusion of the jquery mobile js

Comment: I have edited the question. Is that what you mean by BEFORE the inclusion of the jquery mobile js? Because I still get the error after changing the order of <script> tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the jQuery library before the jQuery mobile library.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>

<script src="master.js"></script>
```

jQuery min javascript file before mobile.js ok?

view: http://jsfiddle.net/7fxQf/24/